# gcc share library initializer function access to current executable name

Tags: c++, c, gcc, constructor, shared-libraries

I have a shared library (gcc on Linux, written in C++, if it matters) which needs to run a constructor function. This constructor function needs to process a configuration file which may reside in the same directory as the executable or in another predefined location. In other words, I need to know the value of `argv[0]` from inside the library constructor function. What's the correct way to do that?

```cpp
static void __attribute__((constructor)) mylib_init()
{
   // need access to config file which is in the same directory as executable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's easy way to get `argv` in the gcc's constructor.

However, on Linux, you can read `/proc/self/cmdline` and get the command name. From which you can work out the directory you're interested in.

`/proc/self/cmdline` will have all arguments, including the command, separated by null character.

Comment: can you please clarify the "easy way to get `argv` in gcc's constructor"? It seems that relying on system calls to get `/proc/self/cmdline` is a kluge

Comment: Here's a way: https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-help/2009-11/msg00006.html (but I'll have to check if it's required to be present). At least on Linux, `/proc/self/cmdline` is a  valid option and guaranteed to work (unless you're looking for portability, say BSD which doesn't have /proc, /proc/self/cmdline is good).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `glibc` provides the path of the currently running executable via `extern const char *__progname_full;` [see here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/init-misc.c)